# Recommendable UI framework for phonegap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

Before posting my question here I have looked across many posts but nothing relevant found. I'm developing an application for both Iphone and Andriod using Phonegap.

I came across with several UI related frameworks :

1.Framework 7
2.Ionic
3.Twitter Bootstrap
4.jQuery Mobile
5.Materializecss
6.jQuery UI
7.Sencha Touch

What is the recommended way of doing this? Meaning-designing a generic UI (tabbars, tables, navigation bars etc') for both Iphone,Android that will give the generic look and feel native?

I need to include Push notification, Camera access, local storage and RSS Feed as a functionality in my application.

Any leads will be appreciated and will be thankful to the core.

Comment: push notification, camera access, local storage and rss feed all this i have done in ionic framework but i dont know about other frame work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saying that you want to develop an application for both android and iOS. Other frameworks will give you nearly same UI for both.I have used Framework7 for both android and iOS. Check this link [framework7 android and ios](http://framework7.io/tutorials/maintain-both-ios-and-material-themes-in-single-app.html). Framework7 provides best UI for ios and for android it also gives material UI.
You can even use requirejs and handlebar/template7 with framework7.
hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahen ! :)  Even I'm slightly more interested in using Framework7 with the phonegap. As I have done a small prototype on it. However, I'm unaware of requirejs and handlebar. Framework7 comes with template7 as far as I know. Can you give some more clarity on this requirejs and handlebar ? Why to use it and advantages of it ?

Comment: @jaiswalabhinav17 In simple words, RequireJS is a module loader,Instead of loading all JS files at same time in html with script tag,RequireJS loads JS files(Modules) as desired.[why to use RequireJS](https://gist.github.com/desandro/4686136).Handlebar is a small template lib similar to template7. check this link[how to use requireJS and HandleBar with F7](http://framework7.io/tutorials/mobile-mvc-apps-with-framework7-requirejs-and-handlerbars.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is probably not any perfect "recommended way of doing this".  You need to just look thru the options and find the one that will work best for you.  Maybe make some small test applications using the different frameworks.  As for me, I settled with Ionic Framework and AngularJS (Ionic Framework uses AngularJS).  There are plenty of plugins out there that you can use from Cordova or on GitHub.  There is also plenty of documentation on each of the frameworks.  Ionic also seems to be working nicely with Windows Phone 10 and they are adding more functionality as well.  Here are the links to the different sites.  Good luck!

[Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/)

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks  buddy ! I'm aware of Ionic too. Just the thing is I'm having the time constraints and don't know Angular JS. So i'm bit afraid of starting my application with IONIC.I know HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap, JS, Jquery(limited). It is having attractive look and feel too. Can you give me some heads up on this ? What is the role of AngularJS and upto what extent it is needed for developing the application ?

Comment: Yea I understand.  Angular is very powerful.  Since you know html and javascript you could probably get up to speed pretty quickly (on the basics anyway).  Angular just helps you build more dynamic UI's much quicker (short explanation).  A primary example of what Ionic uses it for is their [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  An <ion-list> is an [Ionic directive](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionList/) which dynamically manipulates the DOM.  You can create your own directives as well using angular and much much more than what I can type here.

Answer (score 0):

Our company built a data collection app for iOS/Android using Cordova (The parent project to PhoneGap) about 1.5 years ago. We went with jQuery Mobile for the UI and knockout.js for databinding, and if I remember correctly finch.js for routing. The downside we experienced was that the app was probably running at 75% the speed of native apps.

However we recently revisited this project, and decided that we'd much rather have used React.js for the UI. It's very fast which will give your app a more native feel. You could couple that with Bootstrap, which handles the creation of responsive UI elements. And then you could even throw in a theme like [this one](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) which gives a pre-built material design (good for android, looks decent on iOS too in my opinion)